# ¿Como actualizar una imagen cada cierto tiempo mientra en la ventana este activa

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Quisiera hacer un programa que cada cierta hora cambie la imagen mientras la ventana este activa lo mas parecido que encontrado es esto:

```
def Background_Image(self):
    curent_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
    minutes = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    clock = Label(text=curent_time)
    clock.place(x=100, y=100)
    background = Label(self.root)


    if minutes == 44:
        background.config(image=image_day)
        background.image = image_day
    elif minutes == 45:
        background.config(image=image_afternoon)
        background.image = image_afternoon
    else:
        background.config(image=image_night)
        background.image = image_night

    background.place(x=-6, y=34)

    clock.after(200, self.Background_Image)
```

Cualquier apoyo me serviría gracias...